# Remove Home tab with visualforce home tab

Tags: apex, community, salesforce1-app

I want to remove the default home tab with custom vf home tab. Is there a way to achieve. Thanks!!

Comment: You want to use a custom VisualForce page for your home tab without implementing a VisualForce page? What?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Jonathan. Please read again and let me know if there is anything to implement this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the default home tab, I'm going to assume that you are using the Standard Tabs view of communities and not the Community Designer. It is absolutely possible to replace the default home tab. You'll first need to create a Visualforce page and corresponding tab. Then you would just include that tab, in the correct order, via the Communities settings.

Go to Setup > Customize > Communities > All Communities and from the drop-down arrow to the right of your community, select Administration Settings and click on Tabs & Pages to edit the default tabs.

In addition to removing the default home tab from the navigation, you'll also want to hide the tab visibility on the community profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to replace the Home tab in partner portal login. Is there a way to achieve in partner portal? Thanks!!

Comment: Are you asking about partner portal or partner communities? Are you asking about the login page or the home page?

Comment: I am asking fo partner portal and for the home page.